# Shisha Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred six?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chashmonaim began their rule 206 years before the destruction of the second Beis Hamikdash. (The Gemara, Avodah Zarah 9a, gives these figures: 103 years of Chashmonai rulers, followed by 103 years of the Herodian dynasty.)

Interesting, too, that Rambam (Hil. Chanukah 3:1), in summarizing the positive results of the Maccabean revolt, characterizes this as a period when "kingship returned to the Jewish People." Which **perhaps** indicates that (a) he doesn't agree with Ramban (commentary to Gen. 49:10) that the Chashmonaim assuming the kingship was a bad thing, and (b) he also doesn't see Herod and his successors as so bad either.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Sefer Hayashar](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40009&pgnum=255), the Pharaoh of the Exodus (whom it calls Adikam) ascended the throne four years before the Exodus, or 206 years after the Jewish People came down to Egypt.